# Uiscrollview issue help!

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

i have an uiscrollview and i add 3 imageviews. i want to show the user the middle(second) image as the startup imageview. how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated` method, with contentOffset value depending on your imageview size.